# Java - Which hashmap get() method will be faster and why?

Tags: java

I have two hashmaps:

1. hashmap1 with 1000 (key,value) pairs such as (1,one)(2,two)(3,three)(4,four) .. (1000,thousand)
2. hashmap2 with 100,000 (key,value) pairs such as (1,one)(2,two)(3,three) .. (100000,hundredthousand)

which among the following two operations would be faster, viz. hashmap1.get(100) or hashmap2.get(100) and why ?

Comment: have your tried testing ?? , you can test it by writing loop. With may be same value but different key. as you cannot generate one,twoo with loop but that doesn't matter. And then check performance and also let us know the answere

Comment: HashMaps by design have O(1) performance for `get`s.

Answer (score 3):

They'll both run in (about) the same time.

If you take a look at the [`HashMap` API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html):

> This implementation provides **constant-time performance** for the basic operations (get and put), assuming the hash function disperses the elements properly among the buckets.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @azurefrog answer, I'd like to make this point.

It depends on the definition of fast. Asymptotically speaking, both these operations are going to take `O(1)`, and is independent of the size `n`, that is be it 1 or 100,000 or 1MM.

But there are interesting implications that when we consider `HashMap` in a generic sense. It might be affected by the following two factors as well.

1. The underlying hashing algorithm must be collision free.
2. Objects equality is done in O(1) as well.

But for the case in hand, both should take theoretically the same time when speaking asymptotically.